# VBA IE queryselector converting to Selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

i need to convert my code from IE to Chrome with Selenium
ive managed to log in to my server, now i have 3 actions left :
With Internet Explorer i had this code to select an option from drop down list, then click a button to download and save IE popup :

```
ie.document.querySelector("[value='export_selected']").Selected = True

Set Go = ie.document.querySelector("[title='Run the selected action']")
Go.Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))

Application.SendKeys "%{s}"
```

How will i write these lines to use with Selenium Chrome?
Thank you for helping a noob!
Contents :
[image]

Comment: Please share the HTML contents ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this line for selenium

```
bot.FindElementByCss("[value='export_selected']").Click
```

so instead of `.querySelector` use `.FindElementByCss` and use `Click` method.

Comment: Works! , and i used .FindElementByClass("button").Click

Comment: You have to share the HTML as text not as snapshot so as to be able to have a look and test.

Comment: Thanks, i will try to get html text next time, previously i had trouble formatting it. Wanted to ask if this works, when computer is locked? that Selenium Sendkeys work when computer is locked? the reason i need to switch from IE to Chrome

Comment: I have no idea about what you are trying to do, but try using selenium. I think it will be better than using IE.